# How to expand tableview cell on click on button which is located outside the cell in the tableview?

Tags: swift

There is a tableview cell and there is a more button which is located on the tableview not in the cell so I want that when the project run it show only five user data in the tableview cell and other user data is show when the user click on the more button(which is located out side the cell) how do I achieved this?

Thanks for help

You can find the prototype cell image

[image: here]

//Mark:TableViewDelegate

```
extension MembersViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imgarray.count
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tblView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "membTableCell", for: indexPath) as! membTableCell
        cell.profiletabImg.image = imgarray[indexPath.row]
        cell.namelbl.text        =  names[indexPath.row]
        cell.positionlbl.text    =    "Ceo of code with color"
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
    @IBAction func morebutton(sender:UIButton){

    }


    }
```

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The tableview expands automatically if you add data to the array and call the tableview.reloadData() function.

From the Apple's Doc - 
"Call this method to reload all the data that is used to construct the table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and so on. For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible. It adjusts offsets if the table shrinks as a result of the reload. The table view’s delegate or data source calls this method when it wants the table view to completely reload its data. It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows, especially within an animation block implemented with calls to beginUpdates() and endUpdates()."

```
    @IBAction func moreBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        tableviewArray.append("Append your array with remaining items")
        tableview.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: this is my code can you give me an example for this

Comment: Store just five values in the imgarray, append the remaining values in the more button and then reload tableview

Comment: i have only one array and all of the data is on that array then what will i do

Comment: copy the first five elements to a new array initially and append the remaining data to the same array in morebutton

Comment: if data comes from api then what will i do

Answer (score 0):

Return 5 in `numberOfRowsInSection` method if more button is not tapped.
When more button is tapped reload the tableview and return `imgarray.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var dataArr = [String]()
    var expanded = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dataArr = (1..<25).map({ String($0) })
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "\(dataArr.count - 5) more", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(morebutton(_:)))
    }
    @objc func morebutton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
        expanded = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if !expanded && !dataArr.isEmpty {
            return 5
        } else {
            return dataArr.count
        }
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataArr[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```